# Using a Form to Insert Data Into Multiple Tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called PEOPLE with the fields: SIN, SEX, and AGE.

I have another table called PMEASUREMENTS with the fields: SIN, MTYPE, MVALUE, MUNITS.

MTYPE is a type of measurement: length, height, weight, width, depth, speed, volume, etc.

MVALUE is the value of that measurement: 5, 10, 15.4, 200

MUNITS is the unit used for that measurement: cm, mm, m

I want to have a form which can enter data for a new person, and enter 3 different measurements.

I created a form for PEOPLE with the fields I want, and I created another form for MEASUREMENTS.

I tried inserting the MEASUREMENTS form as a subform inside the PEOPLE entry form, and linking them based on the SIN. But it only wants to SHOW me records from a person. How can I make it so that I can add a new person and new measurements for that person at the same time in the same form?

Comment: you're on the right track- a subform is correct. Did you make sure that `Allow Additions` is set to true on the subform? in the record source you are using for the subform updatable? (you can look in the bottom left corner when you try to make a change, it will say `record set not updatable` or something like that)

Comment: Yes allow additions is enabled on the subform. And yes it is update-able as far as I know. I can enter a record and then go back to it and change the value if that's what you mean

Comment: Oh I see, you are not able to add a new parent record (sorry mis read at first). so what happens when you go to add new record? (the right pointing arrow with the yellow start at the bottom of the form)

Comment: It is greyed out! EDIT: Do you mean for the main form or the sub-form. I can't add a record to the sub-form via the conjoined form.

Comment: does the _parent_ form allow addition's?

Comment: Yes it does, it will add a new entry

Comment: I got it. For whatever reason, the allow additions, edits, and deletions had to match on their yes/no values for both forms. Strange.

Comment: yes, it has to be consistent throughout the whole chain.